# Importing a file into jupyterlabs from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I have a file I want to import into a Sagemaker Jupyter notebook python 3 instance for use.  The exact code would be 'import lstm.'  I can store the file in s3 (which would probably be ideal) or locally, whichever you prefer.  I have been searching the internet for a while and have been unable to find a solution to this.  I am actually just trying to run/understand this code from Suraj Raval's youtube channel: https://github.com/llSourcell/Bitcoin_Trading_Bot.  The 'import lstm' line is failing when I run, and I am trying to figure out how to make this work.

I have tried:
from s3://... import lstm.  failed
I have tried some boto3 methods and wasn't able to get it to work.

```
import time
import threading
import lstm, etl, json. ##this line
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import h5py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
configs = json.loads(open('configs.json').read())
tstart = time.time()
```

I would just like to be able to import the lstm file and all the others into a Jupyter notebook instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should  be cloning the Github repo in SageMaker instance and not importing the files from S3. I was able to reproduce the Bitcoin Trading Bot notebook from SageMaker by cloning it. You can follow the below steps

#### Cloning Github Repo to SageMaker Notebook

1. Open JupyterLab from the AWS SageMaker console.
2. From the JupyterLab  Launcher, open the Terminal.
3. Change directory to SageMaker

```
cd ~/SageMaker
```

4. Clone the BitCoin Trading Bot [git repo](https://github.com/llSourcell/Bitcoin_Trading_Bot)

```
git clone https://github.com/llSourcell/Bitcoin_Trading_Bot.git
cd Bitcoin_Trading_Bot
```

5. Now you can open the notebook `Bitcoin LSTM Prediction.ipynb` and select the Tensorflow Kernel to run the notebook.

[image]

#### Adding files from local machine to SageMaker Notebook

To add files from your local machine to SageMaker Notebook instance, you can use [file upload](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/files.html) functionality in JupyterLab

#### Adding files from S3 to SageMaker Notebook

To add files from S3 to SageMaker Notebook instance, use AWS CLI or Python SDK to upload/download files.

For example, to download `lstm.py` file from S3 to SageMaker using AWS CLI

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/bot/src/lstm.py .
```

Using `boto3` API

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.download_file('mybucket', 'bot/src/lstm.py', './lstm.py')
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  The issue is if I want to write my own code with the above functionality but I really appreciate it!

Comment: I have updated answer to include how to download files from S3 or local machine to SageMaker Notebook. See if that helps